# Где хранятся файлы и данные приложения на эмуляторе Genymotion?

Tags: android, android-shared-preferences, genymotion

Для тестирования мобильных приложений есть куча разнообразных эмуляторов. Есть хорошие и откровенно говоря не очень. Для себя я выбрал такой эмулятор, как `GenyMotion`.

У себя в приложении я сохраняю некоторые настройки и потом после перезагрузки тяну определенные переменные из этих настроек. Так формируется кэш, который состоит из этих вот настроек. У меня возник вопрос - как найти этот файлик с настройками, посмотреть какие там есть переменные, и вообще как получить к нему доступ.

После продолжительных поисков в сети, я узнал что искать нужно по такому пути: `/sdcard/Android/data(obb)`. То есть данные по приложениям хранятся в этих двух папках `(data+obb)`. Но ... Мало того что у меня нету папки `obb` , так еще и в папке data у меня есть только три каких-то приложения, которые походу были предустановлены на эмуляторе.

Я подумал, что может есть где-то еще папки с данными приложений, перерыл весь эмулятор, но ничего так и не нашел.

Надеюсь что кто-то уже сталкивался с подобной проблемой, и он мне подскажет что делать в моей ситуации.

### UPDATE

Вариант того как я записываю настройки:

```
sp = getSharedPreferences(REFRESH_TOKEN, 0);
final boolean hasVisited = sp.getBoolean("hasVisited", false);
```

или вот так:

```
sp = getSharedPreferences("url", 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
editor.putString("url", url);
editor.apply();
```

Comment: Покажите как сохраняете.

Comment: @Suvitruf, если я правильно понял, вы спрашиваете про то как я сохраняю файл настроек?

Comment: Именно. Под настройками вы подразумеваете SharedPreferences?

Comment: да, сейчас дополню вопрос с вариантом сохранения

Comment: Проблема только в GenyMotion? На других устройствах нормально всё?

Comment: вы спрашиваете за реальные устройства, или за виртуальные?

Comment: Да без разницы, собственно. На других устройствах/виртуалках вы можете достать эти файлы?

Comment: Ищите тут /data/data/com.example.myapp/shared_prefs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Когда я последний раз работал с `SharedPreferences`, они хранились в `/data/data/package_name/shared_prefs/name.xml` во внутренней памяти. Вы к этим файлам напрямую из файловых менеджеров обратиться не можете.

Comment: у меня вот на телефоне нету папки с названием пакета, вообще нету

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko, если телефон не рутован то эти папки скрыты и потому не видны. На эмуляторах они видны.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, если я правильно понял, мне нужно выйти в самый корень, и там в папке `data` должно быть то что я ищу? или мне нужно с корня карты памяти идти?

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko рут - не корень файловой системы. root - это админские права в системе.

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko, да, ищите `/data` в корне девайса

Comment: там ничего нету, просто пустая папка)) может нужно что-то прописать что-бы папка создавалась? или она автоматом создается?

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko должна быть по-умолчанию. Вы точно во внутренней памяти смотрите, а не на sd карте?

Comment: @Suvitruf, не исключаю что я не там смотрю, как пройти во внутреннюю память? это я так понимаю не sdcard, но как она тогда называется?

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko "Внутренняя память" или "Internal storage".

Comment: Телефон/эмулятор и будет показывать папку `/data` пустой, потому что туда запрещён доступ. Увидеть содержимое можно только с рут-правами, или с помощью Device File Explorer в студии (`Menu->View->Tool Windows->Device File Explorer`)

Comment: @woesss нет. Не вся внутренняя память скрыта.

Comment: @Suvitruf, я **всю** память и не упоминал.

Comment: @woesss,  спасибо)